# How to change the backup and archive destination to a network drive in oracle 11g windows

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, rman

Due to space issue I want to change the backup and archive destination from FRA to a network drive in my system (I'm using windows). I've done the following steps to change the destination:

```
RMAN> CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO '\\192.168.20.200\HOME\DEVELOPMENT\JOE';

RMAN> configure channel device type sbt parms 

sbt_library='//192.168.20.200/Home/Development/Joe/';
```

Now, when I'm trying to `BACKUP DATABASE` I'm getting the following error:

> ORA-19554: error allocating device, device type: SBT_TAPE, device name:
>   ORA-27211: Failed to load Media Management Library

Comment: You're setting the backups to go to tapes. You want to backup to tapes?

Comment: @RenatoAfonso : Can please explain me what you meant by tapes?

Answer (score 2):

Network drives are managed by system as a drive, then for rman, it should be a disk device :

CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '\192.168.20.200\HOME\DEVELOPMENT\JOE';

CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK;

I have never tested something like that, but I think it should work.

Comment: I done the changes as per your suggestion and I'm getting error like this -----------------------RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 05/24/2017 11:41:07
ORA-19504: failed to create file "\\192.168.20.200\HOME\DEVELOPMENT\JOE"
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 5) Access is denied.

Comment: The user running the rman command or the service account running the Oracle service is not allowed to write to the share.

Comment: R : Can you please suggest me the steps to overcome it?

Comment: I think rman run under the oracle service account, so you have to grant write access on the share to the Windows account running the oracle service. BEWARE ! It MUST be a domain account, not a local machine one.

Comment: @ Guillaume R. I've given Administrative account password and when I restarted the service it showing error: ** Windows could not start the Oracle ServicePROD service on local computer. Error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure.**